# how to handle Azure AD SSO authentication on selenium cucumber framework java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ptc-windchill

I have windchill application which uses Azure AD SSO for authenticating users. I want to automate few of the test cases wherein navigating to homepage via selenium is redirecting me to microsoft login page.

Could you please help me with this?

[image]